# Jqgrid multigroup searching

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to understand the search functionality of multiplegroup: true. I am using the below demo:

http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchingDialogAboveGrid.htm

Here if I give client = test5 and in the subgroup client = test6 with 'OR condition', I am expecting two rows. However i get no records to view.

Please help me understand.

Comment: subgroup? but why not just adding OR line?

Comment: I want to have both 'AND' and 'OR' condition. That is (client = test5 and amount = 300) or (client = test6)

Comment: I see, in your example braces are redundant btw

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem which you describe is a bug in jqGrid. I posted the corresponding bug report [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-in-local-searching/#p28113). I will inform you after the corresponding fix will be ready.

As a workaround you can modify the `postData.filters` inside of `onSearch` so that the search requests like

[image]

will be transformed to another equivalent queries

[image]

In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067628/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) demonstrate how one can modify the filter from `postData.filters` *before* the filter will be apply by jqGrid.