# Query on multiplegroup - jqgrid complex search

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with multiplegroup option true for search. My filter looks like the following:

```
{"groupOp":"OR",
"rules":[{"field":"Total_case","op":"eq","data":"29"}],
"groups":[{"groupOp":"AND",
"rules":[{"field":"Total_case","op":"eq","data":"2"},{"field":"percent","op":"eq","data":"100"}],
"groups":[]}]}
```

I have rows with both total case = 2 ,percent = 100 and total case = 29. Since outer condition is "OR" condition, I am expecting two rows. However it displays no record. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems be duplicate from [answer your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14435407/315935). I just wrote the answer on your original question where I confirmed that it's a bug in the current version of jqGrid. As a workaround I suggested to modify requests having `"groupOp":"OR"` and both non-empty parts `rules` and `groups` so that the `rules` part will be inserted as new additional group inside of `groups`.

On the example which you posted one can first use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the JSON string `postData.filters` which you posted to the object form

```js
{
    groupOp: "OR",
    rules: [
        {field: "Total_case", op: "eq", data: "29"}
    ],
    groups: [
        {
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                {field: "Total_case", op: "eq", data: "2"},
                {field: "percent", op: "eq", data: "100"}
            ],
            groups: []
        }
    ]
}
```

Then one could test that `groupOp` is "OR" and both `rules` and `groups` are non-empty arrays. In the case one can move the `rules` part inside of `groups`. In other words one could convert it to the following object

```js
{
    groupOp: "OR",
    rules: [],
    groups: [
        {
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                {field: "Total_case", op: "eq", data: "2"},
                {field: "percent", op: "eq", data: "100"}
            ],
            groups: []
        }
        {
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules: [
                {field: "Total_case", op: "eq", data: "29"}
            ],
            groups: []
        }
    ]
}
```

At the end one can use `JSON.stringify` to convert the object back to JSON string and assign the results back to `postData.filters`.

**UPDATED**: I posted [the pull request](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/pull/417) which describe the changes which will do jqGrid internally during processing of the filtering/searching request.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchingDialogAboveGrid1.htm) uses the fix and it seems that all works correctly now.