# Multiple AND/OR option in jqgrid search

Tags: jqgrid

I am using JQGRID advanced search in my project. Is it possible to have multiple AND/OR conditions for each search rules. That is

```
Name = John AND
Amount < 500 OR
Tax > 30.
```

Basically I want to have the AND/OR condition after each search rule. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by using search option `multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true`

Comment: I am aware of multigroup. But I want to have the AND/OR next to each search rule.

Comment: @user1986736: If it's required you can add new search rule by modifying of `postData.filters` inside of `onSearch` callback. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9067628/315935) for the code example.