# Add advanced search filter jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I want to create an advance filter search in jqGrid. I used  [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066249/jqgrid-change-search-filters-on-submit) to resolve my problem, but there is enough.
In that way, appears only the overlay, but I don't view the dialog.

My jquery-ui version in the 1.10.4 and my jquery-version is 1.11.0.

Any idea?

**EDIT**
this is my code

```
$("#listDaFatturare").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDaFatturare', {edit:false, add:false, del:false}, {}, {}, {},
    {
        multipleSearch: true,
        overlay: 0,
        onSearch: function () {
            var i, rules, rule, $grid = $('#listDaFatturare'),
                postData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'),
                filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);

            if (filters && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                rules = filters.rules;
                for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                    rule = rules[i];
                    if (rule.field === 'name') {

                        rule.field = 'amount';
                    }
                }
                postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
            }
        }});
    });
```

EDIT2:
I try to change the code with this but never change:

```
   $("#listDaFatturare").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDaFatturare', {edit:false, add:false, del:false, refresh:false},
                {},
                {},
                {},
                {multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true}
                );  
          });
```

Comment: You should post the link to the demo or at least the exact code which you use. One sees overlay only if jQuery UI or jqGrid are used incorrectly or if there are *an exception* during processing some callbacks of the advance filter.