# jqGrid dynamically change search operator type on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

This is my jqgrid

[image]

Grid related code

```
var lastsel2;
var containsOrNot = 'contains';
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: "{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/data/item_lookup_management') }}",
        postData: {
            masterGridRowId: {{ VPK }}
        },
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Item No', 'Description 1', 'Vendor Item No','Report Dec','Location','On Hand','Exp balance','Available now','Lead Time','Type', 'Vendor #', 'Status', 'Stocked', 'Product Line', 'Creator'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: "I_ItemNumID",
                index: "u.I_ItemNumID",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '70'
            },
            {
                name: "I_Desc1",
                index: "u.I_Desc1",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '70'
            },
            {
                name: "I_VendorItemNum",
                index: "u.I_VendorItemNum",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_ReportDec",
                index: "u.I_ReportDec",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_BinNum",
                index: "u.I_BinNum",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_OnHandTotal",
                index: "u.I_OnHandTotal",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "R_ClosingBalance",
                index: "u.R_ClosingBalance",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "R_BalanceActual",
                index: "u.R_BalanceActual",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_LeadTime",
                index: "u.I_LeadTime",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_ItemType",
                index: "u.I_ItemType",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_VendorNumID",
                index: "u.I_VendorNumID",
                editable: false,
                align: 'left',
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                width: '100'
            },
            {
                name: "I_Status",
                index: "u.I_Status",
                editable: false,
                width: 100,
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                align: 'left'
            },
            {
                name: "I_isStocked",
                index: "u.I_isStocked",
                editable: false,
                width: 100,
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                align: 'left'
            },
            {
                name: "I_ProductLine",
                index: "u.I_ProductLine",
                editable: false,
                width: 150,
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                align: 'left'
            },
            {
                name: "I_CreatedSysUser",
                index: "u.I_CreatedSysUser",
                editable: false,
                width: 100,
                searchoptions:{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc']},
                align: 'left'
            }
        ],
        ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
            var rowData = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowid);
            window.opener.document.getElementById('productDetail_V_PK').value = rowid;
            window.opener.document.getElementById('productDetail_V_Desc').value = rowData.I_ItemNumID;
            window.close();
        },
        height: 400,
        rowNum: 50,
        rowTotal: 1000000,
        width: 3000,
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: false,
        pager: '#pager',
        shrinkToFit: true,
        sortable: true,
        sortname:"u.id",
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        //multiselect: true,
        loadonce:false,
        onCellSelect: function(row, col, content, event) {
            var cm = jQuery("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
            //alert(cm[col].name);
            if (window.getSelection) {
                selection = window.getSelection();
            } else if (document.selection) {
                selection = document.selection.createRange();
            }
            selectionColumn = cm[col].name;
            selection.toString() !== '' && $("#gs_"+selectionColumn).val(selection.toString());
        },
        rowList: [50, 100, 500, 1000]
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{ del:false, add:false, edit:false},{multipleSearch:true}).navButtonAdd('#pager',{
        caption: "Select",
        buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk",
        onClickButton: function(){
            var myGrid = $('#list');
            selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var rowData = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', selectedRowId);
            if(selectedRowId != null)
            {
                window.opener.document.getElementById('productDetail_V_PK').value = selectedRowId;
                window.opener.document.getElementById('productDetail_V_Desc').value = rowData.I_ItemNumID;
                window.close();
            }
            else
            {
                $(function() {
                    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function() {
                                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        },
        position:"last"
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
        searchOperators: true,
        stringResult: true,
        searchOnEnter : true,
        sopt: ['cn','eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge','bw','ew','nc'],
        beforeSearch: function(){
            if(containsOrNot == "notContains" && containsOrNot != "contains")
            {
                //CODE FOR EXCLUDE EXECUTE HERE
                var i, l, rules, rule, $grid = $('#list'),
                        postData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'),
                        filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);
                if (filters && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                    rules = filters.rules;
                    for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                        rule = rules[i];
                        console.log(rule.op);
                        if (rule.op === 'cn') {
                            // change contains to does not contain
                            rule.op = 'nc';
                        }
                    }
                    postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
                }
            }
        }}).navButtonAdd('#pager',{
        caption: "Contains",
        buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk",
        onClickButton: function(){
            containsOrNot = 'contains';
            $("#list")[0].triggerToolbar();
        },
        position:"last"
    }).navButtonAdd('#pager',{
        caption: "Excludes",
        buttonicon:"ui-icon-disk",
        onClickButton: function(){
            containsOrNot = 'notContains';
            $("#list")[0].triggerToolbar();
        },
        position:"last"
    });
    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('gridResize');
});
```

My grid already has code for triggering the toolbar search.
`$("#list")[0].triggerToolbar();` is doing my toolbarsearch on the click of a button defined in the footer part.

Currently the search is defaulted to `contains`. so when I select text from any column the filter of that column is populated with that selected text. And when I press on the Contains button the triggerToolbar is triggered properly.

What I would like to do? when I click on the `Excludes` button it should fire another triggerToolbar but with a **does not contain filter**. How can I dynamically change the default filter on the particular column?

*Edit* jqGrid version 4.8.2

**UPDATE** With Oleg's another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067628/4841794) and the current answer I was able to achieve this. The code is updated and works as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not easy. You will have to change the operations in operation menu in every searching field. Moreover you will have to add first of all have to add `searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn', 'nc']}` options **in all columns**, because currently there are many fields which have no `searchoptions.sopt`. It means that one can search only by `'cn'`.

Because of complexity of the way I would recommend you to choose an alternative way. I'd suggest you to add `beforeSearch` callback in `filterToolbar`. The callback `onClickButton` for `"Excludes"` and `"Contains"` buttons should set some variable to different value. The variable should be available inside of `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar`. Inside of `beforeSearch` callback you can implement the following logic. If `"Contains"` button is clicked it should return `false` (continue searching). In case of `"Excludes"` button is clicked one should convert the string `postData.filters` to object and go through every element of `rules` and replace `"cn"` value of the `op` property to `"nc"`. Finally one should convert the modified searching rule from object to `string` and return `false` too to continue searching. It should work.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Sorry for the late reply. I did exactly what you said and the code works like a charm. I was able to get more help from one of your other answers here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9067628/4841794) . for changing the postdata filters. I didn't understand your last part though where you say Finally one should convert the modified searching rule from object to `string` and return `false` too to continue searching. What do you exactly mean by return `false`? I ran my code without returning and it still works. Meanwhile I'll update my code for future users.

Comment: Oh and thanks. You've been of great help to me all this time with jqGrid

Comment: @DipenShah: You are welcome! I want to say with the sentence about "convert the modified searching rule from object to string" the following: the `filters` property of `postData` contains `string` in case of local filtering. To modify the filter you need first convert the string `filters` to object (using `$.parseJSON` for example), then modify it and finally convert object using `JSON.stringify` back to string which one need to save as `filters` property of `postData`.

Comment: Oh okay. I think I am already doing that thanks to your previous answers.

Comment: @DipenShah: About return `false`: `beforeSearch` callback can be used *to break* the searching by returning `true` from `beforeSearch` callback. So I wrote that one should return `false` from the callback. On the other side you are right: if one don't returns any value from `beforeSearch` callback then the next test `if (!bsr)` will be true with `undefined` exactly like with `false` and one can save returning false.

Comment: You are right. with this way I only check the rules for that specific rule and I don't have to return false. Its just a preference. One can add `return false` if they wish.