# Jqgrid : toolbar search options - range select from a drop down

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need help to do range select on jqgrid data using the filter toolbar drop down - I checked the sopt options it only has -

```
['equal','not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','contains','does not contain']
```

and I am not able to find any clue on how to do range with this on the toolbar. I have a drop down that has values like `"All", "1-4", "5-9"` on my filter toolbar and when I select say `'1-4'` I want the grid to populate all rows that fall in that range. I looked at a bunch of examples for filter from stackoverflow and trirand itself but they all seem to be for the search box.
I am grateful for any help to achieve this, Thanks.

Comment: Do you use local filtering or filtering on the server?

Comment: Hi Oleg,  As of now local filtering, may need to extedn this to the server. I was able to modify your the multi word example to do range filtering.

Comment: Yes, I would suggest you the same. The code from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) shows how to replace one searching rule to multiple rules. Using the approach you can implement any new searching rule. In case of server side searching the implementation is even more easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this filter by range based on sample multi-word sample- http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MultiwordSearchingToolbar.htm. Most of the code is from above mentioned sample with minor changes. Modified baseed on feedback from Oleg to make it as le and ge.

```
    modifySearchingFilter = function (separator) {
            var i, rules, rule, parts, group, str;
            var filters = $.parseJSON(this.p.postData.filters); 
            if(separator != '-')
              return;
            if (filters && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                rules = filters.rules;
                for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                    rule = rules[i];
                    if (rule.op === 'range') {
                        // Range should only have 2 parts lowerbound and upperbound
                        parts = rule.data.split(separator);
                        if (parts.length == 2) {
                            if (typeof filters.groups === 'undefined') {
                                    filters.groups = [];
                            }
                            group = {
                                groupOp: 'AND',
                                groups: [],
                                rules: []
                            };
                            filters.groups.push(group);
                            // Breaking to 2 rules one le and other ge
                            group.rules.push({
                                        data: (parts[0]),
                                        op: "ge",
                                        field: rule.field
                                    });                             
                            group.rules.push({
                                        data: (parts[1]),
                                        op: "le",
                                        field: rule.field
                                    });                                                                     
                            rules.splice(i, 1);     
                            i--; // to skip i++                             
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
            }
        },


 //using range op so that it is not confused with other ops
 setRangeSearchSelect = function(columnName) {
        grid.jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
        {
           stype: 'select',
           searchoptions: {                                 value:buildRangeSearchSelect(),
                 sopt:['range'],                            
        }
     });
    };

 grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar',  
    {
     stringResult:true, 
     searchOnEnter:true,      
     defaultSearch:"cn", 
     beforeSearch: function () {  
       modifySearchingFilter.call(this, '-');    
     }});
```

Comment: It's strange that you use `op: "cn"` for the range implementation. I think that correct would be `'ge'` for one part and `'le'` for the second.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I caanot use op:"cn". I will modify, thanks

Comment: @Siva VG : hi , i have problem in search in reng, please give me any demo, thanks.