# JQGrid DateTime Advanced Filter

Tags: jqgrid

I am stuck here - last thing to get done before going production.

The date coming from oracle is on the following format: "8/14/2012 10:46:48 AM"

I am using the following on the jqgrid:

```
{ name: 'CreationDate', index: 'CreationDate', formatter: 'date', formatoptions:    { 'srcformat': 'ISO8601Long', 'newformat': 'm/d/Y - g:i A' }, sorttype: 'date', width: 95, align: 'right', resizable: false },
```

I have the following displaying on the grid: "08/14/2012 - 10:46AM"

The problem is when I try to use the advanced filter it doesn't work. My guess is because of the time, any suggestions on how to solve this?

**UPDATE**

Oleg, I copied the code you posted with your changes and still nothing. I am using the advanced filter. Thanks for all your help, I really, really appreciate it. I wish I could send you some beer to Germany :o)

[image: Not working sample]

[image: Working sample with full text]

Comment: More info, the json data shows the data as "2012-08-14T10:46:48". If I enter 2012-08-14 on the filter, it filters fine, but if I enter 08/14/201 it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you use `g` format inside of `newformat` which are not currently supported in jqGrid for the local filtering/searching. You can try to use `H`  format instead. Alternatively you can use the fix which is described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11800979/315935).

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDate2.htm) shows that one can use Advanced Searching dialog with `formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { 'srcformat': 'ISO8601Long', 'newformat': 'm/d/Y - g:i A' }` after applying the fix which I referenced. You can just try the demo and input the same data (`10/04/2012 - 5:55 PM`) which I used on the picture below. You have to see the following results:

[image]

**UPDATED 2**: During preparing of another demo for you I found one more bug in internal [parseDate](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L82-142) function. The problem is that the current implementation of `parseDate` function works correct only if the date which are need be parsed contain the same elements as specified the format. For example the date `10/04/2012` will be incorrect parsed using `'m/d/Y - g:i A'` format. To fix the bug one can include the line

```js
if(typeof date[k] === "undefined") { continue; }
```

as the first line of the body of [the loop](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L98). The fixed version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` you can get [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.src-fixed1.js).

In the demo I use `multipleSearch: true` option of [jqGrid searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching). As the result one can specify the interval of dates like

```
10/04/2012 <= x <= 10/05/2012
```

The corresponding Searching Dialog will look like on the picture below and you will be able to filter by intervals of dates

[image]

Comment: Oleg, thanks for the reply but still doesn't work. I changed the format to H     { 'srcformat': 'ISO8601Long', 'newformat': 'm/d/Y - H:i A' } but didn't help the filter only works with I type the wat the data is coming on json "2012-08-14". If I tried to implement other answer then I have to type everything, including the time. Any other way you think I would do this? Thanks again.

Comment: Is there anyway to write a custom filter just for this date column?

Comment: @user1409155: Sorry, but I don't see any problem in the filtering of the data after applying the fix which I referenced. I made the demo for you which demonstrate that all works correctly. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: thanks again Oleg. The problem with the filter is that I have to type the whole thing to search. i.e. I cannot filter all 10/05/2012, it will not return any results. I have to enter 10/05/1012 - 7:10AM. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1409155: See **UPDATED 2** part of the answer.

Comment: @user1409155: You are welcome! You wrote about "Advanced Filter". So I understood you wrong. There are only [Advanced Searching Dialog](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching) or [Toolbar Filter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching). So I supposed that you mean "Advanced Searching" before you posed the screenshorts. The searching for the interval of dates is not directly supported in jqGrid. To implement this you can use `beforeSearch` callback of `filterToolbar`, but the implementation would be very tricky.

Comment: @user1409155: It you decide to try the way with `beforeSearch` I would recommend you to read [the following my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935). Modifying of the demo from the answer you will be able to implement what you need. In the demo I used the structure of filter which corresponds to `multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true` options of the searching and which `filters` structure are described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options).

Comment: @user1409155: By the way, as I wrote the part "UPDATED 2" of my answer I drunk beer at the same time. I am currently in Swiss in the business trip at one customer. So I wrote some answers at the stackoverflow in Hotel after the work. I am glad that I could help you and it's enough for me to have best wishes from you.

Comment: Hey, Oleg. I am still stuck. Sorry man! I am not trying to search interval dates, I am trying to use the Toolbar Filter (sorry I said it wrong before) to match on the date only disregarding the time. The problem I am having is that the filter only works if I enter the date and time as you can see on my screenshot #2, if I enter just the date screenshot #1 it doesn't work.