# change value of textbox in search box before find

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

i am trying to implement complex search functionality in jgrid. But i want to change the value that a user specified in a search box before user presses find button.

[image]

1. Here you can see the values `17 20 35 36 37 53 54` and i want those
   values comma saperated so before i hit find i want to change the
   values in a text box so can anyone tell me how can i do that ?
2. more over i want to know how can i customized the look of this
   search box forexample  instead of `id` , `is in` i want some user
   friendly UI in which user can simple put the values and hit find ,
   but i dont know how to change the look of this search box in inject
   our own look and make the search box non dragable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) where I shown how implement even more complex changing of the user input as you need.

In case of Searching dialog you can use [onSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) callback in the same way like one uses `beforeSearch` for the [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching).

The main idea is that one can get the reference on the internal `postData` parameter of jqGrid with respect of `getGridParam` method. The `filters` property of the `postData` represent the filters serialized as the JSON string (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching#options) for details). So you can convert `postData.filters` to object (using `$.parseJSON`) modify if like you as need, convert back to JSON string (using JSON.stringify) and place the results back in `postData.filters`. If you do all the changes inside of `onSearch` or `beforeSearch` callback the modified filter will be used.

Comment: @Hunt: I am currently at customer. I'll try to answer on the question shortly later when I'll come to hotel.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` to split it to an array on the spaces, and then `.join()` the array again, using a comma as the delimiter (default anyway).

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function(){
  var value = this.value;
  this.value = value.split(' ').join(',');
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mJaqm/

Comment: I don't want to make an answer basically replicating yours just because you didn't wrap it in a blur function. Can you put it in a blur function so I can upvote?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - Done, but you could have edited it, I wouldn't have minded ;-)

Comment: how would i know on which textbox i should use onblur there could be more textboxes and its jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the `onBlur` event of the textbox, which fires when the cursor is taken away:

```
$("#theid").blur(function() {
    value = value.split(' ').join(',');
});
```

Comment: how would i know on which textbox i should use onblur there could be more textboxes and its jqgrid

Comment: Do one thing, in firebug, try getting the `ID` and use this way!

Comment: Well all the ids are managed and assigned dynamically by jqgrid and they might get changed so not possible

Comment: Okay, in that case, give an `ID` to the parent `div` or the enclosure. Now target that like `$("#theid input[type='text']")`. Simple?

Comment: sorry but u r getting wht i am saying , there could be multiple textbox in that div and even if i access with index of input then also its not a good solution in terms of sociability