# how to customiz data before send to server in jqGrid search

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

i'm starter in jqGrid. i write this code for Genereate Grid

```js
grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jQGridHandler.ashx',
    postData: { ActionPage: 'Report5',type:'Fill' },
    datatype: 'json',
    height: 530,
    colNames: ['id','UnitPrice'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Id', sortable: true, search: true, editable: false, hidden: true,
            key: true },
        { name: 'UnitPrice', shrinkToFit: true, width: 50,
            searchoptions: {
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', , 'le', 'ge'],
                dataInit: function (elem) {
                    $(elem).keyup(function () {
                        var str = $(this).val();
                        str = str.replace( /,/g, "" );
                        $(this).val(addCommas(str));
                    });
                }
            }}
    ],
    gridview: true,
    search: true,
    rowNum: 100,
    rowList: [100, 200, 300],
    pager: '#pager',
    viewrecords: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    footerrow: true, userDataOnFooter: true, altRows: true,
});
grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true },
    {},
    {},
    {},
    { multipleSearch: true });
grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn', stringResult: true });

function addCommas(nStr) {
    nStr += '';
    var x = nStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

i want user when in search box select unitPrice and type number, number 3 char 3 char sperate with `,`, i write function addCommas and work good, bute when user enter price and press search button the unit price not send to server.
example in this picture

[image]

and after click in search button

[image]

please help me. thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways how you can modify the searching filter before sending to the server.

First of all I would recommend you to call `change` event explicitly everytime when you change the data in the input field. Searing Dialog hold internally representation of the searching filter and modify it in the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler. So adding `$(this).change();` or `$(this).trigger('change')` could fix some of your current problems.

By the way you have seen that the information about the searching filter will be send to the server as `filters` parameter. You can get it as `filters` property of `postData`. To get the reference to `postData` parameter you can use `grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData")`.

The callback [beforeSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching#calling_convention) of `filterToolbar` is one place where you can access the filters before sending to the server. [onSearch](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:singe_searching#options) is another callback used by searching dialog. To have common way I would recommend you to use `beforeRequest` callback of jqGrid. Inside of the callback you can get `postData` using `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData")` and if has `filters` property you can modify it. The example of modification of `filters` property you will find in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953934/315935) for example.

Comment: thanks, for help me. @Oleg you are very expert in js and jqGrid plugin. i very like work like you.